# Testing web components with jsdom

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, web-component, rollup, native-web-component

I have a web component I've built which is bundled (using [`Rollup`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/)) into a UMD and ESM package. The `src/index.js` basically looks like this.

```js
import html from 'template.html';
import css from 'styles.css';

export class MyComponent extends window.HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
  }
}

export default (function() {
  window.customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
})()
```

I'm well aware about how weird this looks, and I'm open to suggestions on cleaning this up so testing actually works.

I'm trying to test my web component using `mocha` and `jsdom-global`. The problem is I can't get the component to mount. In other words, this fails:

```js
import jsdomGlobal from 'jsdom-global';
import { expect } from 'chai';

import { MyComponent } from '../dist/my-component.esm';

describe('test', function() {
  let jsdom;

  before(function(){
    jsdom = jsdomGlobal('', { runScripts: 'dangerously' });
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = `window.customElements.define('my-component', (${MyComponent}))`;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  })

  after(function() {
    jsdom();
  });

  it('mounts', async function() {
    await window.customElements.whenDefined('my-component');
    expect(window.customElements.get('my-component')).to.exist;
  })
})
```

I've also tried *not* wrapping in a new `window.customElements.define` call because I assumed the IIFE would just execute once the file is referenced but that doesn't seem to be the case?

As an aside, if anyone knows how to test the `/src` files directly instead of the `/dist`, that would be awesome. I assume there's some way that `mocha` and `rollup` could work together to do a better job in identifying coverage. As it stands right now, coverage just shows a single line of failures not anything against the lines in the source.

Comment: Testing WebComponents in JSDOM is a poor choice, because _usually_ you will want to use various WebAPIs, that JSDOM does not or is only partially supporting. JSDOM is not a real browser, it is meant to run unit tests, but for anything else I really suggest you use a proper, real test environment. [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) and [Web Test Runner](https://modern-web.dev/docs/test-runner/overview/) are good choices and they are also pretty fast on contemporary hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have *some* success after trying all sorts of things.

```js
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import fs from 'fs';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { promisify } from 'util';

const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

async function getHTML() {
  const script = await readFile(resolve(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'my-component.umd.js'));
  return `<html><head><script>${script}</script></head><body></body></html>`;
}

describe('my-component', function () {
  describe('browser context', function() {
    let window, document;

    before(async function() {
      const html = await getHTML();
      const dom = new JSDOM(html, { runScripts: 'dangerously', resources: 'usable' });
      window = dom.window;
      document = window.document;
    });

    it('defines a custom element', async function() {
      await window.customElements.whenDefined('my-component');
      expect(window.customElements.get('my-component')).to.exist;
    })
  })
})
```

So this passes the assertion but because the test has no idea about the script, there's no coverage metrics.

```sh
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

It would be nice to be able to test *and* report coverage, but this'll have to do for now.

Comment: That works now? You made me a happy person! Thanks!

Comment: Actually I've streamlined it a bit since then. https://github.com/ddamato/code-anatomy/blob/master/test/dom.js

Comment: ah ;) ill try that .. looks fine. I combine that with the new test runner in node:test on the  18x release and get really fast tests for components